# how can send ajax call with looping id number parameter in url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want send ajax call with loop parameter named [id] in url starts request.php?id=1 ends id=9
and send every call after 3 second .
I'm a beginner in the JavaScript, I don't know where to start the idea, this is my code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'request.php?id=1',
            data: {apiId:actionBtn},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#addApi').css("opacity",".5");
            },
            success: function(response){

            }
        });
```

Comment: Look at the setInterval function to begin with. Did you google how to set a timer in javascript, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make the `id` into a variable `let id = 1;`. Then you can use the JavaScript `setInterval` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function to make a function-call every x seconds.

```
let id = 1;

// you can use a "fat-arrow" function or a function reference, look at the docs
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  // your code here...
  // use the variable "id" and increment it
  i++;

  // stop the interval when id is greater 9
  if (id > 9) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 3000); // 3000 is the time in milliseconds
```

Comment: thx worked , Can I make him wait for the each reaquest until get reponse or send successfuly ??

Comment: You can utilize the success callback of jquery's Ajax function: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ by wrapping the call in a function itself with a ID parameter and calling the function again with id+1 as parameter. Similar to here, you can add a "if" to cancel this recursive call if id is greater than 9. That solution would not need the setInterval anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a loop
for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i += 1) {
  // create a timeout
  setTimeout(() => {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            // set the id
            url: `request.php?id=${i}`,
            data: {apiId:actionBtn},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#addApi').css("opacity",".5");
            },
            success: function(response){

            }
        });
  }, i * 3000)
}
```

Comment: This code calls all url at the same time

Comment: Fixed the issue

Comment: thx worked , Can I make him wait for the each reaquest until get reponse or send successfuly ??